# Returning multiple elements in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

[In this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/0xarkg0j/1/) I have a regex that should return functions from a string.

```
var regex = /(\w+\s*\([^)]*\))/g
var array = regex.exec("func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)");
console.log(array)
```

The `array` variable should contain two elements `func1 (1, 2)` and `func2 (3, 4)`, instead it returns the entire string. What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: match worked, why exec does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns a single match at a time. [To use `exec` to get all the matches, it need to be used with `while` loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches)

```js
var str = "func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)";
var regex = /(\w+\s*\(.*?\))/g;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can also be used to get all the matches in a single statement.

```
console.log("func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)".match(/(\w+\s*\(.*?\))/g));
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0xarkg0j/2/)

```js
console.log("func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)".match(/(\w+\s*\(.*?\))/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var re = /(\w+\s*\([^)]+\))/g; 
var str = 'func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    alert(m[0])
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use match here not exec:

```
"func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)".match(/(\w+\s*\(.*?\))/g);
```

exec is meant to be used in a loop, as it will still retrieve all matched subexpressions. In your code you will only get the first match.

working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/raquku/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications in the generated code with Regex101.com,

```
var re = /(\w+\s*\([^)]*\))/g; 
var str = 'func2 (3, 4) + func1 (1, 2)';
var m;
var results = [];
var counter = 0;
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    results[counter] = m[counter]
    counter++;
}
console.log(results)
```